# Is there a name registrar yet?

Tags: name-registrar

Months ago the idea of a "Global Name Registrar Contract" was thrown around. There is code to deploy one out there, but is there an official one that official clients (geth / Mist / etc) will use by default yet?

Answer (score 2):

There is [EtherID](http://etherid.org/) which has 15k names/domains registered already.

[image: ether id]

It's a DApp by the way and works directly on your geth/eth client.

To enable it, run allow geth access by etherid.org like that:

```
geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "http://etherid.org"
```

The most secure way to work with EtherID is through the mist browser. The developer pre-release is available [here](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.3.6) (v0.3.6).

Source code is available on [github](https://github.com/lexansoft/EtherID.org).

Comment: The problem is that it seems useless if the average user doesn't know about it. (See: Alternate DNS servers that never really caught on.) This sort of thing really has to be integrated into Mist or geth.

Comment: it is fully compatible with mist and geth.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. An average user downloads the Ethereum Wallet. They type "bob" in the address fields. Does the Ethereum Wallet start using EtherID for resolution?

Comment: that's what etherid does, you type "bob" and you end up on an ipfs link.

Answer (score 2):

An Ethereum Request for Comment (ERC) titled "[Default Ethereum Name Registrar](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/26)" is on Github so it is in progress.

The primary author is Alex Van de Sande (avsa@ethdev.com) who is employed by the Ethereum Foundation and is directly working on Mist.

Answer (score 2):

[Adding another answer instead of editing my last one, in case the "ENS" in my last answer is useful for historical reasons... ]

The [Ethereum Name Service](https://ens.domains/) "...offers a secure and decentralised way to address resources both on and off the blockchain using simple, human-readable names."

The documentation, including an FAQ, can be found here: http://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/

Bidding on a name via an auction is covered in a previous question: [How can I bid in an ENS auction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15887/how-can-i-bid-in-an-ens-auction)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ENS](https://blog.makerdao.com/2015/11/11/announcing-ens-decentralized-icann-for-ethereum-registry-top-level-namespaces/) (Ethereal Name Space).

There's a talk from DevCon1 available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7nyBYSEYXE).

Comment: Will this be implemented by default in any official Ethereum software? (geth or Mist)

Comment: It's being developed by [Nexus](http://nexusdev.us/), which I believe is a private firm. I don't believe there's anything to say this will be used by default, either.