# How can I bid in an ENS auction?

Tags: parity, ens

So https://registrar.ens.domains flat out doesn't work. So I tried using https://www.myetherwallet.com/#ens with a parity wallet, but that gives "bad instruction": https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0e0b9cd94a70c7b3894a973f61c707a3746190b655a1f683096f726b563b778a The value says 0 ETH but my screenshot from myetherwallet has ETH to bid, I'm not sure if that's the cause.

Has anyone managed to bid on a pre-existing auction? Is there an alternative way of bidding on an ENS auction?

Comment: Can you expand on "flat out doesn't work"? What problem do you get, and can you provide info from your browser's developer console? Your MEW bid definitely failed because you sent no ether along with it.

Comment: @NickJohnson At the time of writing. I'm sure you've some recollection of our conversations on GitHub and Reddit. ;)

Comment: you have to add extension meta mask I believe

Answer (score 3):

The UIs might have bugs that are being fixed.

https://gitter.im/ethereum/go-ethereum/name-registry is where questions can be asked and answered in real-time.

An alternative way to bid is given in the [ENS docs](http://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/userguide.html#placing-a-bid).

Make sure to read the docs and below is the given example.

### [Example](http://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/userguide.html#placing-a-bid)

```
var bid = ethRegistrar.shaBid(web3.sha3('name'), eth.accounts[0], web3.toWei(1, 'ether'), web3.sha3('secret'));

ethRegistrar.newBid(bid, {from: eth.accounts[0], value: web3.toWei(2, 'ether'), gas: 500000});
```

It is essential to [Reveal bid](http://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/userguide.html#revealing-your-bid) during the reveal phase:

```
ethRegistrar.unsealBid(web3.sha3('name'), web3.toWei(1, 'ether'), web3.sha3('secret'), {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 500000});
```